# Separate data from 1 column into 2 in r

Tags: r, spread

I have a dataset of football teams and their Win/Loss results from 2009-2017. Currently the Wins and Losses are in the same column, one after the other, and I want to create a new column for the losses.

A sample of the data looks like:

```
Football <- data.frame (
    Season = rep ("2009", 10),
    Team = rep (c("ARI", "ARI", "ATL", "ATL", "BAL", "BAL", "BUF", "BUF", "CAR", "CAR")),
    Value = c(10, 6, 7, 9, 7, 9, 6, 10, 8, 8)
)
```

I would like the final output to show:

```
Season    Team    Wins    Losses
2009      ARI     10      6
2009      ATL     7       9
2009      BAL     7       9
```

and so on. There are also several other variables but the only one that changes for each Season/Team pair is the "Value".

I have tried several iterations of spread() and mutate() but they typically make many more columns (i.e. 2009.Wins, 2009.Losses, 2010.Wins, 2010.Losses) than I want.

Thanks for any help. I hope this post turns out alright, its my first time posting.

Cheers, Jeremy

Comment: So the formatting is not great but each "2009" in the desired output should be the start of a new row

Comment: Where are Wins and Losses coming from? You can accomplish this with aggregate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a column of "Winloss" and then `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
Football %>%
  mutate(Winloss = rep(c("Win", "Loss"), n()/2)) %>%
  spread(Winloss, Value)
#   Season Team Loss Win
#1   2009  ARI    6  10
#2   2009  ATL    9   7
#3   2009  BAL    9   7
#4   2009  BUF   10   6
#5   2009  CAR    8   8
```

#### data

```
Football <- data.frame (
  Season = rep ("2009", 10),
  Team = rep (c("ARI", "ARI", "ATL", "ATL", "BAL", "BAL", "BUF", "BUF", "CAR", "CAR")),
  Value = c(10, 6, 7, 9, 7, 9, 6, 10, 8, 8)
)
```

Comment: Or `Football %>%
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  mutate(Winloss = c("Win", "Loss")) %>%
  spread(Winloss, Value)`. This has the benefit of producing a warning if any team has nrows != 2

Comment: Thanks so much akrun and Renu, especially for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Using `reshape2` package

```
> Football$WL <- rep(c("Win", "Losses"), nrow(Football)/2)
> 
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(Football, Season + Team ~ WL, value.var="Value")
  Season Team Losses Win
1   2009  ARI      6  10
2   2009  ATL      9   7
3   2009  BAL      9   7
4   2009  BUF     10   6
5   2009  CAR      8   8
```